# TypeScript: Is it possible to define a class that creates an instance of a function?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript is it possible for a class to be a constructor of a function instance? I envision something like:

```
class SomeThing {
    (name: string) {
       // do something with name
    }
}

let thing = new SomeThing();
thing('John Doe');
```

Answer (score 4):

It's technically possible (it requires some hacks I'm not going to write here) but you really don't want to do this; here's why.

The `new` operator creates a new *object* (not function) whose `__proto__` is the `prototype` of the operand. This means you can't possibly have a callable thing returned by the `new` operator, *unless* you explicitly return something else out of the constructor.

But if you return something else out of the constructor, then `thing instanceof SomeThing` is going to be `false`, and you're not going to be able to use `prototype` methods of the class from `thing`. So at that point it's not really behaving like a `class` at all, and you're better off just having a factory *function*, which can do whatever it wants.

Comment: And to add to @Ryan's excellent answer: You do not need a 'class'  to achieve what you are trying to do. You can just create a `function` that returns another `function`. If you need you can use the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (the outer function) to "store" additional configuration.